# Weird interposer cable for Alienware 18 HDDs. How can I use my HDDs on a normal PC?

Tags: hard-drive, raid

Sooo I'm trying to recover my HDDs from my fried Alienware 18 laptop. Since my warranty expired the manufacturer has disowned me and has been absolutely no help. I took the computer apart and pulled the HDDs to find they were attached with this odd looking cable:
https://www.parts-people.com/index.php?action=item&id=21465

I tried to stick them directly in my computer but no luck there. I think it has something to do with raid.

The end that plugs into the laptop is not a SATA cable is it some proprietary port?
Is there some adapter available?

Comment: "I tried to stick them directly in my computer but no luck there." Writing "no luck there" is an insufficient description. This is the moment of truth where to get diagnostic information from. "I think it has something to do with raid." Again, this is not a description one could base a diagnosis upon. Compare this to your user name where you obviously spent much more effort. This is just a feedback why I never answer such questions.

Comment: Regardless of what `the end that plugs into the laptop` is, the other ends are SATA plugs.

Answer (score 2):

The Alienware cable is just a special cable they use on their systems.  It's basically a proprietary plug on one end and a sata connector on the other.

Just unplug the cable completely from the hdd.  That will expose the hdd's native sata interface and the native power connector.  At this point you have a very standard drive and can connect it to just about anything you want to.

NOTE that if you had these drives configured in some kind of raid configuration, you might need to make sure both drives are plugged into a recovery system and that it is capable of reading the raid configuration.  If the drives were simply mirrored, you should be able to just plug one of them into any standard sata controller and access the data.

The caveat here is whether or not Alienware is using a 3rd party raid controller or windows built-in software raid capabilities.  This could determine what you need on the recovery system in order to read the data.

Either way -- the drives themselves are standard.  Remove that funky cable and go from there.

Comment: Even more likely Intel fake RAID.